# Create a menu CNN iOS app style

Tags: android, ios, menu

I downloaded the CNN iOS app and I seen the wonderful menu!

I post 2 screen

[image: look at CNN logo]

[image: wonderful menu]

Now I'm asking how can I create that in my application. I will develop in iOS and Android but the same application for Android hasn't that menu..

It's possible to create this menu in Andorid?
Has anyone some advice to create that?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got solution: Create one view with listiview, and one button with background photo. Than take the view out of screen. If the view is x = 320 y = 300 set y = -300 in sotryboard element postition settings and place the button in the top corner.
On button action make a animation of the 2 graphic object of y = +300. That's all.

```
- (IBAction)makeTheMagicWithButton:(id)sender {

//at first click y + 300 and view comes in
//at the 2nd click y - 300 and return back out the screen
float y;
[sender setSelected:![sender isSelected]];
if ([sender isSelected]) {
    y = +300;
    self.buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"menuICONSreturn.png"];

} else {
    y = -300;
    self.buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"menuICONS.png"];
}


//animation move the view
[UIView transitionWithView:self.view duration:0.5 options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowAnimatedContent animations:^{[self.magicView setFrame:CGRectOffset(self.magicView.frame, 0, y)];}
                completion:nil];

//animation move button menu
[UIView transitionWithView:self.view duration:0.5 options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowAnimatedContent animations:^{[self.magicButton setFrame:CGRectOffset(self.magicButton.frame, 0, y)];}
                completion:nil];
//change icon
[self.magicButton setBackgroundImage:self.buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Hope it will help someone..

[image: before]

[image: after]